# Is the role of public key/private key determined arbitrarily or mathematically?

Tags: ssh, private-key, public-key-encryption

I have read about conflicting information about the roles of public/private keys.

In one article([Asymmetrical-key algorithms](https://medium.com/codeclan/what-are-encryption-keys-and-how-do-they-work-cc48c3053bd6)), it says:

> Simply put each party, say Alice, picks a private random value, inputs this into a key generation program, and receives two keys.  It is arbitrary which of these is made public and which is kept private, but the privacy of the private key is paramount.

While in many other articles, they suggest that private keys is always for decryption and public keys encryption. Or private keys are for the party being authenticated while public keys are authenticating ones.

So my question is, are private keys called 'private' only because you keep them private, or because they have some mathematical merits that fundamentally differentiate them from their public counterpart?

Comment: This question is duplicated on [crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76234/is-the-role-of-public-key-private-key-determined-arbitrarily-or-mathematically); please don't post duplicates, just use the most appropriate stackexchange site. Also, there are already very similar questions on [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172274/can-i-get-a-public-key-from-an-rsa-private-key) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696472/given-a-private-key-is-it-possible-to-derive-its-public-key).

Comment: [*Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you see conflicting information is that some of the information is about public key encryption systems and some of the information is about RSA. Unfortunately, the Medium article you linked to seems to go out of the way to confuse these two things and I'd strongly suggest you just ignore it. It, completely incorrectly, describes specific details of RSA as if they were properties of public key encryption systems generally.

In elliptic curve systems, for example, private keys are typically integers while public keys are typically points on a two-dimensional curve. They are definitely not interchangeable in those systems.

Comment: Is RSA already useful and common enough to learn for an absolute beginner?

Comment: Yes, but don't actually rely on anything you've done without having it checked by an expert. It's easy to have it work but not get any real security for very subtle reasons.

Comment: I read from AWS's documentation that `The keys that Amazon EC2 uses are 2048-bit SSH-2 RSA keys.` How could a mature website like Amazon adopt RSA if it isn't reliable? I'm very concerned now.

Comment: The problem is not that RSA isn't reliable, it's that it's a powerful and dangerous tool that requires deep expertise to use correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. So in RSA, there is no fundamental difference between the public keys and the private keys, is this right?

Comment: Right. The two keys form a pair. Neither can easily be derived from the other (unless extra information is included in the private key) and either can undo the other.

Comment: Let me clarify, so in RSA the private keys are not mathematically different than the public keys. You keep one of the two private, so it becomes 'private' key. Right?

Comment: But the private keys do look longer every time when I examine the two.

Comment: What you're looking at are not RSA private keys. They're a structure that is part of an implementation of a cryptosystem based on RSA that contains at least enough information to derive the actual RSA private key. There is a huge difference between RSA itself and real-world cryptosystems that use RSA. That's one of the reasons it's so difficult and dangerous to try to use RSA directly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: _"Neither can easily be derived from the other"_ does not apply to RSA as commonly practiced even when the public exponent _e_ is not included in the private key (as it often is, see [`RSAPrivateKey`](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=56)). The reason is that _e_ is typically small, which allows it's determination from _(n,d)_ by trial and error up to 32 bits, and better methods for much larger values.